# How to pass double pointer to an array element in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, structure

So I have this *piece* structure here:

```
typedef struct piece
{

    block* blocks;

    unsigned short numOfBlocks;
    unsigned short color;

    unsigned short width;
    unsigned short height;

    signed short minX;
    signed short minY;

} piece;
```

Each piece has a pointer to an array of blocks. which is another structure I have made.

Further on I have a function to create these pieces dynamically during runtime that looks something like this:

```
piece* generateGamePiece(unsigned short size)
{

    piece* Piece = NULL;

    Piece = malloc(sizeof(*Piece));
    
    if (Piece != NULL)
    {

        if (size > 0)
            Piece->blocks = malloc(size * sizeof(*Piece->blocks));

    }

    ...

    return Piece;

}
```

To free the memory allocated by these pieces, I have a delPiece function that looks like this:

```
void delPiece(piece** Piece)
{

    free((*Piece)->blocks);
    (*Piece)->blocks = NULL;

    free(*Piece);
    *Piece = NULL;

}
```

So I can easily create and destroy a single piece like this:

```
piece* newPiece = NULL;
newPiece = generateGamePiece(5);

...

delPiece(&newPiece);
```

But if I have a pointer which points to an array of pieces returned by a function, something like this:

```
piece* pieceArray = NULL;
pieceArray = generatePieceAray();
```

And I then try to delete every piece in the array:

```
for (unsigned short i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PIECES; i++)
    delPiece(&pieceArray[i]);   
free(pieceArray);
pieceArray = NULL;
```

I get a compiler warning that the function "expected ‘piece **’ but argument is of type ‘piece *’" at the line "delPiece(&pieceArray[i]);"

How can I resolve this? What is the proper way to pass a pointer to a pointer to an array element?

Comment: Did you notice that the type of `newPiece` and `pieceArray` are the same?

Comment: Change your `delPiece` function to accept a `piece*` parameter, no need for `piece**` there.

Comment: There is no proper way to pass `&pieceArray[i]` to `delPiece` because it simply cannot deal with such a pointer in any way, shape or form. It can only work with a pointer that was returned from `malloc`. `&pieceArray[i]` was not returned from `malloc` (for any `i > 0`) so you cannot pass it there.

Comment: `piece* Piece = NULL;

    Piece = malloc(sizeof(*Piece));` Though this is correct, it is confusing and potentially dangerous. First step: remover the parentheses in `malloc(sizeof *Piece);`

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thank You! I changed 'piece* pieceArray' to 'piece** pieceArray' and changed 'generatePieceArray()' so that it returns a double pointer to a piece where each piece* is dynamically located inside of the function. Now delPiece() works as intended!

Comment: I suggest to drop the term "double pointer". What you mean is a "pointer to pointer".